# Is there a difference between cookies set manually in browser and cookies set by server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, react-gtm-module

I am experiencing a strange behaviour in my react app. When running app on a local machine, manually added cookies (in browser > application > cookies) are removed after a first network call. When deployed everything is fine. I managed to find the pr after which this behaviour started to manifest, and it is after implementing google analytics tracking with 'react-gtm-module'. So this module is somehow removing all the cookies from the browser and then setting its own. But only in local dev.

How can anything remove a cookie like this?

Comment: without a single line of code, the answer is ... yes, code can remove cookies that are removable

Comment: all the relevant code is in the library :/ could you please elaborate, what is a removable cookie? i mean you need a name to remove it right?

Comment: it was a consent issue.... i ll post an answer fro posterity

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out... Issue was that in the local environment consent to store cookies was not given.